# How to prove strong convergence in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Suppose $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $W^{m,p}$ then show that
>   $u_n$ converges to $u$ strongly in $W^{m,p}$.

I tried: 
If  $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $W^{m,p}$ then $f(D^{\alpha}u_n)\rightarrow f(D^{\alpha}u)$ for all $|\alpha|\leq m$, where $f$ is in Dual of $L^p$. So
$$|f(D^{\alpha}u_n)-f(D^{\alpha}u)|\leq \|f\|\|D^{\alpha}u_n-D^{\alpha}u\|_{L^p}$$
But here i want the reverse of this inequality. Don't know how to proceed further. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this is true in general.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1288590/does-weak-convergence-in-w1-p-imply-strong-convergence-in-lq